# "No display specified error" generated by tinkter when starting Python program at bootup with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, display, python-turtle

I have a Python program that displays weather information in graphical form on a Respberry Pi. The program uses Turtle and tkinter to generate the graphics. Running the program from the command line .i.e. "$ python3 DisplayProgram.py works properly.

I added a startup service (DisplayProgram.service) to systemd so that the program would start up at reboot.  However, when I test the program with "$ sudo systemctl start DisplayProgram.service" command, the error _tkinter.TclError: no display and no $DISPLAY environment variable is generated.

From reading other posts, I am aware that this error occurs because, prior to the calls to tkinter, no parent program has set the $DISPLAY environment variable to specify the screen where the graphics are to be displayed.  (I assume that when, running the program from the command line, the Python interpreter sets the appropriate environment variables.)

And so, the simple question is how to define the $DISPLAY environment variables in the absence of a parent program/server?

Comment: You need to run your script after the X server is up.  Check how to set dependency on services using `systemd`. I am not familiar on `systemd`, so I cannot tell you how.

Comment: ..or, as an ugly quick-fix, add an `import time` and `time.sleep(10)` at the beginning of your script to wait for X server to come up

Comment: Look at #4 and #5. https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/